# Eclipse Android Adb failure

Tags: android, adb

I'm having problems starting my adb in eclipse and looked for all answers here for this issue such as stopping an antivirus called COMODO Defense+ which i actually don't have or copying files from \platform-tools to \tool........ but non worked.

I get the following erros when ever reseting adb or trying to run my android application:

```
[2014-04-07 16:58:55 - Trucks] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-04-07 16:58:55 - Trucks] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-04-07 16:58:55 - Trucks] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Users\........\adb.exe' and can be executed.
```

and the adb is directed in this directory for sure.

Also i get pop messages:

```
Adb failed to restart!
Make sure the plugin is properly configured.
```

and

```
Attempting to restart adb, but version check failed!
```

I had a randsome virus a while ago that locked my files, but i have unlocked them all now, could the virus had done something with eclipse that changed something related to the Adb?

Comment: Open task manager and kill adb.exe then start eclipse

Comment: @Maverick i tried this before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before

at first kill adb.exe from task manager;

then turn off antivirus firewall - (or Put adb.exe in extensions).

at last start adb.exe.

try it , i hope it work;